# getting "segmentation failed" error in strrev function implementation

Tags: c

```
void main() { 
    void strrev(char *); 
    char *p="GOOd";
    strrev(p);
    printf("%s",p);
}

void strrev(char *str) { 
    char temp, *end_ptr;
    if( str == NULL || !(*str) ) return;
    end_ptr = str + strlen(str) - 1;

    while( end_ptr > str ) 
    { 
        temp = *str; 
        *str = *end_ptr; 
        *end_ptr = temp; str++; 
        end_ptr--; 
    } 
}
```

i am getting the error segmentation failed can any one help me out how to sort it out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is that in the following:

```
char *p = "GOOd";
```

the compiler is allowed to place the string literal in read-only memory.

Any attempt to modify the string pointed to by `p` results in undefined behaviour.

Try changing the above line to:

```
char p[] = "GOOd";
```

I don't see anything wrong with the `strrev()` function itself.

Comment: so direct swapping in the string is not possible?

Comment: @S.A.Rahman: It is, as long as you're using a suitable way to allocate the memory for the string (e.g. `char p[] = "GOOd"` or `malloc`/`strdup`).

Answer (score 8):

The statement:

```
char *p = "GOOd";
```

Defines a string literal "GOOD", pointed by an pointer `p`.

You are trying to modify this string literal through the `strrev` function which results in **Undefined Behavior(UB)** and the crash.

The problem with string literals is they are stored in a read-only(Implementation defined) memory location and user programs are not allowed to change that.If a program attempts to do so it causes an UB.

So instead of using a string literal You should use an array.

You should be using:

```
char p[] = "GOOd";
```

Comment: thanks did it... but wat should i learn from this mistake... and even how many other situation these kind of errors (UB) ill fall?

Comment: @S.A.Rahman: There are a lot of scenarios which result in UB.The C standard clearly mentions them as such but IMHO Experience is the way to go about it, You try things,You get stuck, try to find mistakes, ask questions here if you cant get any help.You make mistakes,you learn from them,With practice you will know what the common scenarios which cause UB.

Comment: if the string is defined as char *p = "GOOd";
then how the standard library function operates it?

Comment: @S.A.Rahman: The important concept to learn here is, If you have a pointer to a string literal then the string cannot be modified,And it is your job as a programmer to ensure that it is not modified through (your)pointer which points to it.It implies,You should not pass such a pointer to any function(standard library or your own) which tries to modify the string pointed by the pointer,If you do so like you do now,there will be no warning just an UB and/or crash.You should follow this rule always,thats about it.